# printing the value of a query using php

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to print out the value of a query but what appears on the screen is the query itself!

```
mysql_select_db($database_databasestudents, $databasestudents);
    $result = mysql_query("Select name from country where id = '$s';",$databasestudents);
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($result) ;
echo $r;
```

where $s is an integer

This is what I get on the screen:
 SELECT name FROM `country` WHERE id='3'

3 is the value of $s

Comment: Currently, you're just printing the value of the variable and the result is as expected. To get the results of the query, you'll have to use a database function, such as `mysqli_query()` and then fetch the results using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` or similar.

Comment: Also, don't quote integers in SQL. Please use a prepared statement for this.

Comment: Now that you've completely changed your code, the code supplied would not produce the error you're describing. The original code did. Describe the new problem.

Comment: @AmalMurali can you check the modification? I used both functions and its printing the word "Array" now. still not printing the value, any idea? The result should be just one element not an array

Comment: You need to read some basic tutorials on mysql interaction. do a print_r() on that array and you'll see your data.

Comment: @Jessica thanks Jessica it worked. I apologize but I'm new to both mysql and php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the query in order to get the result. Maybe this will get you started:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=YOURHOST;port=YOURPORT;dbname=YOURDB', 'YOURUSER', 'YOURPASSWORD');
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM `country` WHERE id=?';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($s));
while ($result = $stmt->fetchObject())
{
    echo $result->name;
}
```

Comment: I did run it on my browser, it is printing this:
"SELECT name FROM country WHERE id='3'"

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the query first

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

and then loop though the results

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

You have created a string containing your query.
You must instantiate a database connection and then execute your query.

Answer (score 0):

`$r` is an array, not a string. You need `print_r($r);` or `var_dump($r);`, not `echo`